DW/ BI dimension modelling, combining facts
I have read the DW/BI kimball design v3, everything seems logical to me, but there is one point I am struggling with. I work for a streaming company (OTT). We have different star schemas for business processes, for example:
fact_user_subscription (this is a temporary fact table that defines the user subscription, activation date, expiration date and subscription related measures / dimensions) and a second one like vod_watch_fact where we also have consolidated dimensions with subscriptions such as user, the granularity in both tables is one row per transaction, or one row per browsing session.
What concerns me is how to combine this data at the BI level, we are using Looker.
I'm 100% sure that a business user would want to filter some lookup events based on subscription data, like where it was purchased or how. And almost all processes in our company are related to user subscriptions. I knew joins were a bad idea, but Looker doesn't support multipass, and I don't want to create large fact tables at the ELT Dataform level to simplify updating and maintenance. Perhaps I'm missing something here.
I'm tried to create join rules at explore level at looker, using relationship. But not sure is it correct way to handle it.

Looker does not support multipass SQL directly, you can achieve effective data integration across star schemas using LookML’s relationships and joins, denormalization techniques, and possibly PDTs or aggregate tables. By carefully designing your Looker explores and leveraging database optimizations, you can provide business users with integrated insights while maintaining performance and scalability in your BI environment.
